# Log4Net custom appender initialization

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-appender

I want to write a CosmosDB appender for Log4Net because I wasn't able to find one that works and I need to understand the best way to initialize it.

Below you can find my work in progress code.

Now the Cosmos DB client initialization is inside the Append method, but I believe that will be better call it just one time.

I tried to put it inside the MyCosmosDBAppender class initialization, but in that moment properties doesn't yet contain a value.

So my question is...exists a method that is called just one time that can be used for initialization?

Or the only solution is to insert a check inside Append in order to execute it just the first time?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using log4net.Core;
using log4net.Appender;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;

namespace MyCosmosDB
{
    public class MyCosmosDBAppender : AppenderSkeleton
    {
        public string EndPoint { get; set; }

        public string AuthKey { get; set; }

        public string Database { get; set; }

        public string Collection { get; set; }

        private static DocumentClient client;

        public MyCosmosDBAppender()
        {
        }

        override protected void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            ConnectionPolicy policy = new ConnectionPolicy { ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct, ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp };
            client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(this.EndPoint), this.AuthKey, policy);
            client.OpenAsync();

            LogObject obj = new LogObject();
            obj.Id = "AKWP";
            obj.Name = "Test name";
            obj.Publisher = "Pubblished by...";

            CreateItemAsync(obj);
        }

        public void CreateItemAsync(LogObject item)
        {
            client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(this.Database, this.Collection), item);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the ActivateOptions overridable method?

Comment: You need to configure the new appender to be used by log4net

Comment: Thanks Klaus, for some reason the first time that I made a search I ignored ActivateOptions that is perfect for my needs!